# How to expose localhost:8080 to other users?

Tags: spring-mvc, tomcat7

I'm using spring mvc 3.x and tomcat 7 locally on windows 7and I want to expose `http://localhost:8080/webapp` to some marketing folks here at work but when I expose it as `http://myhostname:8080/webapp` my co workers are saying they are not seeing anything (mouse wheel spins).

What do I nee do setup locally on windows to expose 8080 to ppl in my domain for a POC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit your *server.xml* configuration and add **address="0.0.0.0"** property like this:

```
<Connector port="8080" address="0.0.0.0" maxHttpHeaderSize="8192"
           maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="25" maxSpareThreads="75"
           enableLookups="false" redirectPort="8443" acceptCount="100"
           connectionTimeout="20000" disableUploadTimeout="true" URIEncoding="UTF-8"/>
```

It will allow everyone to access your tomcat.

If it doesn't work, check your windows firewall to expose 8080 output port.

Answer (score 1):

please ask your friends to try with your IP address in place of hostname in url. It should work. If thats working, tell members who are accessing the service to add a host entry in their local systems.

Make sure that you all are in the same LAN.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried IP and two ppl cannot still get to the page. I tried the IP myself and of course it works.  Any other ides? I have done this before in .net asp.net mvc4 but I haven't touched .net or IIS locally in 4-5mo. Not sure what is going on with tomcat or spring.